# Open weather map is not returning accurate temperature

Tags: android, weather, weather-api, temperature, openweathermap

The JSON which I am getting after hitting the open weather map api is not having the accurate temperature. I have cross checked the temperature data by mapping the temperature which I have got after hitting the open weather map api to some other applications data like yahoo weather, Google weather etc. There is a huge difference in the temperatures.
I am listing the url below with cityId for which I have checked the temperature.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1271631&APPID=064129b86c99c35c42d531db251b99e3&cnt=16&units=metric

Comment: maybe one of them uses Celsius while the other user Fahrenheit

Comment: @ZAhmed, here units=metric will return temperature in Celsius and I have changed other applications Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius to find the difference and it was marking a large difference.